# Allow elastic beanstalk role in resource based policy in cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have deployed elastic beanstalk which has a role `MyEBSRole` in `Account A`. I would like to give this role access to `Event Bridge` in other account (`Account B`) (cross account). In `Account B` Event Bridge, I have added the following resource based policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "mysid",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A-ID>:role/MyEBSRole"
    },
    "Action": ["events:PutRule", "events:ListRules", "events:DeleteRule", "events:DescribeRule", "events:DisableRule", "events:EnableRule", "events:PutTargets", "events:RemoveTargets"],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:<Region>:<Account-B-ID>:rule/*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEqualsIfExists": {
        "events:creatorAccount": "${aws:PrincipalAccount}"
      }
    }
  }
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListRules operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<Account-A-ID>:assumed-role/MyEBSRole/i-0b68xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: events:ListRules on resource: arn:aws:events:<Region>:<Account-B-ID>:rule/*
```

If I replace the principal in resource based policy to this:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A-ID>:root"
}
```

Then I am able to get result via `cloud shell`, but with Elastic beanstalk it is still not working.

I also tried with `arn:aws:sts::<Account-A-ID>:assumed-role/MyEBSRole/i-0b68xxxxxxx` in principal but it also does not work.

Could anyone please, indicate what is wrong or missing there? Thank you.

Comment: Does the role `MyEBSRole` have the `events:...` permissions? In cross-account setups you need the permissions on both sides. The originating account needs to allow the role to perform the action and the target account needs to allow it as well.

Comment: @luk2302 I guess no. let me try.

Comment: @luk2302 It worked! thanks. You can write as answer. I can mark it as accepted :)